# Measuring Stats of Employees for a Call Center

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am attempting to do historical analysis of call stats, the obstacle I am facing is that my agent's have the option of changing positions. For example Front/Back office, I would like to be able to differentiate their stats by role per year. If a front office agent is in front office from January to march, but then gets promoted to back office in April; I would like to time stamp their stats or perhaps create a table that references their time in that role to make sure the stats I am looking at are historically accurate. Currently I am using stats on a excel workbook and using power bi to visualize the stats year to date, and month over month. Right now I am encountering the fact when an agent's role changes their historical stats gets moved to their new position.  I'm open to any suggestions or logic.

Comment: Check this please: [Help Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Hello, please provide a clearer question and provide sample data along with the column with the value that you would expect

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post